# asp.net create uzer wizard getting a handle on controls in custom steps

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-membership

I have added an extra step to my uzerwizard

```
<asp:TemplatedWizardStep id="stpPayment" runat="server" Title="Payment">
        <ContentTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmbSubs" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                            Width="200px">

                            <asp:ListItem Value="month">Monthly Subscription</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="year">Annual Subscription</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

i am successfully navigating to the new step

```
protected void NewUserprofileWizard_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (NewUserprofileWizard.ActiveStepIndex == 0)
    {
        NewUserprofileWizard.ActiveStepIndex = 1;

    }
}
```

but I cant get access to the dropdownlist from my codebehind
note: i can get a handle onto the controls in the 1st (createuser) step.

but any controls in the next step always return a null.

this is the code i am using

```
DropDownList cmb = (DropDownList)NewUserprofileWizard.WizardSteps[1].FindControl("cmbSubs");
```

i always return a null.

note that this works just fine

```
TextBox tmp = (TextBox)NewUserprofileWizard.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Email");
    userProfile.AccountEmail = tmp.Text;
```

problem seems unique to custom steps

Thanks for the help

---

Tried Gregors suggestion. no luck. mine always comes up as null.

[image]

if thsi helps any:
my wizard is inside a user control..
the page that uses the user control is inside a master page.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears that today my google foo was doing much better

because i am in a templateswizardstep, i have to cast the wizardstep into the templatedwizardstep.

from here i can now find the control. whooohoo!

```
TemplatedWizardStep step = (TemplatedWizardStep)NewUserprofileWizard.WizardSteps[1];
cmb = (DropDownList)step.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("cmbSubs");
```

Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here is little sample I have created for you, first aspx code:

```
        <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" OnNextButtonClick="CreateUserWizard1_NextButtonClick">
            <WizardSteps>
                <asp:WizardStep runat="server" Title="My Custom Step">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbSubs" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
                        Width="200px">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="month">Monthly Subscription</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="year">Annual Subscription</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </asp:WizardStep>
                <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server" />
                <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server" />
            </WizardSteps>
        </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

And now the code to find first dropdown:

```
    protected void CreateUserWizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CurrentStepIndex == 0)
        {
            //get instance to dropdown...
            string selectedValue = null;
            string controlId = null;
            foreach (var item in CreateUserWizard1.WizardSteps[0].Controls)
            {
                DropDownList ddl = item as DropDownList;
                if (ddl != null)
                {
                    selectedValue = ddl.SelectedValue;
                    controlId = ddl.ClientID;
                    break;
                }
            }       
        }
    }
```

Of course you can also find your dropdown like this:

```
DropDownList cmbSubs = CreateUserWizard1.WizardSteps[0].FindControl("cmbSubs") as DropDownList;
```

Happy coding!

Comment: thanks gregor. but the control lisst always has null in it. see image i added to my post

Comment: Please remove ContentTemplate from your aspx code and try again. For more details check aspx structure from my sample.

Comment: apologies for late reply. I cant just remove the contenttemplate. if i do my aspx wont render. it gives an error about TemplatedWizardStep not having a public property named <table>