# asp.net use value from one control in a wizard step as value of another in a subsequent step

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, aspwizard

I have next to no knowledge of asp.net and I need a quick solution.

I have a `asp:WizardStep` to which I have added a dropdown, like so:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="picklistname" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem value="abc" selected="True">abc</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem value="def">def</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem value="ghijk">ghijk</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

That shows up when I run it.

In a later wizard step I have a textbox control, and I want to put the value of the previous dropdown into it, something like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="value from picklistname" ID="...
```

Can this be done and if so, how?

The page language is vb.

I don't have access to the code behind - in fact I can't even find the code behind file so I suspect it has been compiled and the source code is not there anymore.

**EDIT**

I have managed to get a bit closer:

I added a hidden field (regular html - not asp control) outside of the wizard.

I then added onchange="copyToPickList(this)" to the dropdown control.  The copyToPickList function just copies the value of the dropdown to the hidden field.

In the step with the text box, I can add a onclick and call a function that copies the hidden field into the textbox.

So now my question is how to get the textbox having this value automatically (on page load)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - its a bit naff, but I added some script in the textbox step that populated the textbox after a certain time elapsed giving the control time to render the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. You can easily assign value to textbox

```
  var textboxId = document.getElementById("txtBoxId");
  var e = document.getElementById("picklistname"); 
  var dropDownValue= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  textboxId.value = dropDownValue;    
  textboxId.focus();
```

Comment: OK - tried that and it doesn't work.  The problem is that the dropdown isn't on the page at the same time as the textbox and yet the wizard docs say that values from previous steps are available

Comment: sorry. i searched more.it shows code behind solutions [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351826/asp-net-create-uzer-wizard-getting-a-handle-on-controls-in-custom-steps)